Android Wear - windowSwipeToDismiss does not seem to work with API 33
My user need to scroll in all direction inside our wearable app. The older solution does not seem to work anymore.
<item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss" tools:ignore="WearBackNavigation">false</item>
I have this property in my style. It work on older device with API 30. I can reproduce it easily simulator api 33 from android studio.
android:windowSwipeToDismiss="false"
Also tried that without success.
